# Java2D based Game engine lags when there's no input

Tags: java, canvas, game-engine, java-2d

I am messing around with my custom built game engine, which uses Java2D APIs to draw on a Canvas (Active rendering).

The thing that I noticed is that a simple scene with a square moving around gets rendered more smoothly if I either actively keep pressing keys on my laptop's keyboard or move my mouse around (inside the frame boundaries). If I don't do anything the movement feels sluggish.

My game engine uses fixed timestep rendering where multiple updates can occur per single drawing.

My frame structure: JFrame has a child Canvas which employs a thread to perform updating / rendering.

Operating system is Linux, can it be a focus problem? FPS counter reports the same fps in both cases.

My loop code is this:

```
while(active) {
    g = (Graphics2D) bs.getDrawGraphics();
    now = System.currentTimeMillis();
    double delta = now - prev;
    while(delta >= 0) {
        update(dt);
        updateTicks++;
        delta -= dt;
    }
    render(g);
    bs.show();
    if(System.currentTimeMillis() - fpsTimer > 1000) {
        fpsTimer += 1000;
        System.out.printf("FPS: %d\n", updateTicks);
        updateTicks = 0;
    }
    prev = now;
    try {
        Thread.sleep(5);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

I don't think that's the issue though.

**update**: there's a slight fps drop: 5/7 updates per second if I don't provide input to the frame..Something is going on behind the scenes..

Comment: Have you checked the time interval between ticks to be sure that it is definitely fixed time steps?

Comment: Yeah, it is fixed time step because I enforce it in my code. But that's not the main issue. I am asking myself why the increase in smoothiness if I move the mouse over the frame.

Comment: I suspect it is forcing additional repaints of the canvas by invalidating the area due to the mouse being over the canvas/frame.

Comment: So, something which does not depend directly from my code, more like a side effect?

Comment: Possibly, although it's something which you may wish to look into in terms of your current code. Perhaps you also need to be invalidating the paint, to force a redraw. I'm no expert in this TBH, but it's worth checking out. I've only done a tiny bit of invalidation of paint draw operations in the past myself

Answer (score 0):

Check on which thread is your input logic processing.

Comment: AWT Event dispatch thread handles game input, so it's a different thread.. I tried disabling the event handling logic and this behavior keeps showing up.

Comment: Try to force redraw the form.